# How can a class implementing an interface have a method with an arg of a slightly different type?

Tags: typescript

This is the scenario:

```
interface A {
    foo(bar: number | string): void;
}

class B implements A {
    foo(bar: number): void {
        console.log(2 * bar);
    }
}

const x: A = new B();

x.foo("hello world")
```

This compiles fine, but in my opinion it is breaking the type-safety unexpectedly. Why is it that the argument of `foo` in `B` can have a subtype of the argument of `foo` in `A` and still satisfy TypeScript?

The other way around makes sense (`bar` in `A` having a subtype of `bar` in `B`), but not this. I have not been able to find an explanation to this.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The compiler tells you the right thing when using a function type outside the class, `string | number` isn't assignable to `number`: https://tsplay.dev/mL8oKm.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The question you linked does indeed answer my question. I wasn't aware of this concept (covariance/bivariance) in programming, which explains why I couldn't find anything when googling earlier. Thank you!